# Ant Clustering Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I am currently working on implementing the standard ACA by Lumer and Faieta(1994) in Python but have hard time get some part of codes to work.

So basically, I need to set up a 2D-grid virtual world with a random spatial distribution of 'specs' initialized according to some density parameter DENSITY and then implement NUM_ANTS ants that wander randomly around the virtual world space, without interacting with the specs.

Any insight?

Comment: Maybe if you added a link to what you are talking about and some code you've written. And maybe an explanation of what it is supposed to do and what's missing.

Comment: so the idea of the algorithm is to initially project the input data items in the bi-dimensional grid and scatter them randomly.

Comment: You need to specify what "density" means.  Is it just average density (i.e. density = total # specs / area)?  If so, just choose density*area random x,y coordinates and place specs.

Comment: Since it said 'some density parameter', i think it would work the way you said it.